# How to timeout user input for turn-based game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a basic command-line math game in Python 3. The game shows a user a basic addition problem, the system waits for the user to hit enter, then it displays the answer and then the next problem.

I want to introduce pressure on the player by including a time-out per turn. If the player doesn't hit enter before 3 seconds are up, the game is stopped and a message is displayed.

**Problem:** How to interrupt the `input()` after 3 seconds have passed.

**Research so far:**

- [Python multithreading interrupt input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031762/python-multithreading-interrupt-input)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

**Illustrative code snippet:**

```
import signal

import sys


def ask_question():
    input("3 + 4 = ?")


def print_answer():
    print("7")


def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    print("sorry you ran out of time")
    sys.exit()

MAX_TURN_TIME = 3

ask_question()
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
signal.alarm(MAX_TURN_TIME)
print_answer()
signal.alarm(0)
```

Comment: Are you on linux or windows? have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: This is very platform-specific, I think. I've seen many such questions upvoted and answered seemingly well, but none of the answers actually worked, because it seems like `input` doesn't care much about any signals or attempts to terminate the thread: it still sits and _blocks_ until a newline is received.