# Timed input in python 3 for Mac and Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, timer, python-multithreading

I need a timed input for python 3 on both Mac and Windows which, if the user runs out of time, automatically chooses one of the options. Every other answer for a question I've seen only terminates after user presses 'Enter'. I need it to terminate regardless of any 'Enter' pressed or not.

For example, in my chess program, if no input is given after 5 seconds, I need it to automatically choose "Q". Also if the input is not in ["Q", "R", "B", "N"] then I also need it to choose "Q".

The following code doesn't work. It'll ask for the input then wait forever; the timer doesn't work at all.

```
def countdown():
    global timer
    timer = 5
    for x in range(timer):
        timer -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

countdownThread = threading.Thread(target=countdown)
countdownThread.start()

while timer > 0:
    promotedPiece = input("Promote to Q, R, B or N? >  ").upper()
    if timer == 0:
        break

if timer == 0:
    if promotedPiece not in ["Q", "R", "B", "N"]:  # If not valid input, choose Queen
        promotedPiece = "Q"
        print("Queen auto selected")
```

Comment: You might want to build this off the events in the `keyboard` module rather than the builtin `input` function.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very interesting question, and many people have been looking at timed inputs:

- [Python 3 Timed Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input)
- [waiting for user input in separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078363/waiting-for-user-input-in-separate-thread)
- [How to set time limit on raw_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-raw-input)?
- [Python multithreading interrupt input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031762/python-multithreading-interrupt-input)

About the retrieving of a single character very good answers are provided for all platforms:

- [How to read a single character from the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

### Solutions

#### Linux

The general consensus is that when you are using `Linux` the following works good (taken from [jer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933402/10961342) answer):

```
import signal

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    raise AlarmException

def nonBlockingRawInput(prompt='', timeout=20):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        text = raw_input(prompt)
        signal.alarm(0)
        return text
    except AlarmException:
        print '\nPrompt timeout. Continuing...'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    return ''
```

#### Windows

But when you are on Windows, there is no real good solution. People have been trying to use threads and interrupt signals, but when I tried them out I couldn't get them working properly. Most direct solutions are summarized in [this](https://gist.github.com/atupal/5865237) gist from `atupal`. But there are many more attempts:

- [python: windows equivalent of SIGALRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm)
- [Timed input with Python 3 and Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010120/timed-input-with-python-3-and-windows-7)

The last thing I could come up with for your specific situation is to simulate a key press after the timeout. This key press will then be the user input (even though the user didn't input one, for the program it seems like he did).

For this solution I created the following files:

- `listener.py`: with the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/10961342

  ```
    class _Getch:
        """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
    screen."""

        def __init__(self):
            try:
                self.impl = _GetchWindows()
            except ImportError:
                self.impl = _GetchUnix()

        def __call__(self):
            return self.impl()


    class _GetchUnix:
        def __init__(self):
            import tty, sys

        def __call__(self):
            import sys, tty, termios
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch


    class _GetchWindows:
        def __init__(self):
            import msvcrt

        def __call__(self):
            import msvcrt
            return msvcrt.getch()


    getch = _Getch()
  ```

- `keys.py`: with (unicode) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13290031/10961342

  (from the question: [How to generate keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events))

  ```
    import ctypes
    import time

    SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

    PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)

    KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004
    KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002


    class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                    ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                    ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]


    class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                    ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]


    class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                    ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                    ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]


    class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                    ("mi", MouseInput),
                    ("hi", HardwareInput)]


    class Input(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                    ("ii", Input_I)]


    def PressKey(KeyUnicode):
        extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
        ii_ = Input_I()
        ii_.ki = KeyBdInput(0, KeyUnicode, KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
        x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_)
        ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


    def ReleaseKey(KeyUnicode):
        extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
        ii_ = Input_I()
        ii_.ki = KeyBdInput(0, KeyUnicode, KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
        x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_)
        ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


    def PressAltTab():
        PressKey(0x012)  # Alt
        PressKey(0x09)  # Tab

        time.sleep(2)  # optional : if you want to see the atl-tab overlay

        ReleaseKey(0x09)  # ~Tab
        ReleaseKey(0x012)  # ~Alt


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        PressAltTab()
  ```

- `main.py`: with the following

  ```
  import time
  import multiprocessing as mp
  import listener
  import keys


  def press_key(delay=2, key='Q'):
      time.sleep(delay)

      # All keys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN
      keys.PressKey(int(hex(ord(key)), base=16))  # 0x51
      keys.ReleaseKey(int(hex(ord(key)), base=16))  # 0x51


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      process = mp.Process(target=press_key)
      process.start()

      question = "Promote to?"
      choice = ('Q', 'B', 'R', 'N')

      print(f"Promote to? {choice}\n>>> ", end='')
      reply = (listener.getch()).upper().decode('utf-8')
      process.terminate()

      if reply not in choice:
          reply = 'Q'

      print(f"Promoted piece to {reply}")
  ```

#### Explanation

`listener` makes sure to only listen to a single key stroke, while `keys` gives us the option to simulate a user key. The `main` calls a Process that will automatically send a `Q` to the stdin after a certain `delay` in seconds. A process has been made so we can call `process.terminate()` before the `Q` is send, if we have a user reply (much more complicated with a thread).

Notes

- This only works if you directly read from the cmd console. If you use an IDE, you have to emulate the terminal. For example in Pycharm, you have to select `Emulate terminal in output console` in `Run/Debug Configurations`.
- The terminal window has to be selected, otherwise the `Q` will be send to whatever window is currently active.

```
Promote to? ('Q', 'B', 'R', 'N')
>>> Promoted piece to Q

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
Promote to? ('Q', 'B', 'R', 'N')
>>> Promoted piece to N

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Gui alternatives

Even though it is hard to make it work directly in python, there are alternative solutions when you take the whole program into account. The question seems to refer to chess, and when you build a full game (with gui) you can often use their build in keyboard capture. For example:

- [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.poll) (`pygame.event.wait(timeout in milliseconds)`)
- [opencv-python (cv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494101/using-other-keys-for-the-waitkey-function-of-opencv/14494131) (`cv2.waitKey(delay in milliseconds)`)

Then you can set a variable `promoting` and if that is true, return the pressed key or an alternative key after the wait period.

---

### Edit

A minimal working example in `pygame` would be:

```
import pygame


def set_timer(timeout=5):
    print(f"To which piece do you want to promote?")
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, timeout * 1_000)
    return True


def check_timer_keys(event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.unicode.upper() in ['Q', 'R', 'N', 'B']:
            print(f'Key press {event}')
            return False
        else:
            print(f"Invalid key! {event}")
            return True

    if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
        print("Exceeded time, user event")
        return False

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    running = True
    timer = False

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            # Should be before the T call, other wise it also handles the `t` call.
            if timer:
                timer = check_timer_keys(event)

            # When pressing T, start the promotion question.
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode.upper() == 'T':
                    timer = set_timer(timeout=2)

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
```

Whenever you press the `t` key a timer start to run with a 2 second timeout. This means that after 2 seconds you will get a  custom `pygame.USEREVENT`, which means that the user failed to answer within the time. In the `check_timer_keys` I filter for the `Q, R, N and B` key, hence other keys are not processed for this specific question.

A current limitation is that you can mix the `USEREVENT` call if you promote multiple pieces within the `timeout` period. If you want to prevent this, you have to add a counter that indicates how many `USEREVENT`'s  call are estill being processed (if number is larger than 1, wait until it is 1).

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on the Pygame alternative? I don't see how to use the event.wait for this.

Comment: I added a minimal working example for pygame.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with `async`, it's a very simple solution to this problem, with the `aioconsole` (`pip install aioconsole`) library:

```py
import asyncio

from aioconsole import ainput # async version of input()

async def get_choice() -> str:
    try:
        coro = ainput("Promote to Q, R, B or N? >  ")
        choice = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print()  # go to next line past ">" of prompt
        choice = "Q"
    return choice.upper()

async def main():
    print("You chose", await get_choice())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

As managing input in different environments is quite different, it is a good idea to use a module where someone else has taken care of it. `pynput` does what you want. Be careful as it has some [caveats](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html).

Here is the implementation of `timeout_input` and `timeout_getchar` functions that are good enough for general use. In your case, `timeout_getchar` should be a perfect match:

```py
from pynput import keyboard
from time import monotonic


def timeout_input(timeout:float, prompt:str='', echo=True, None_on_timeout=False):
    """Read string with timeout.
    
    Reads keypresses until enter is pressed or timeout occurs. On enter,
    returns the characters read. On timeout the return value depends on the
    None_on_timeout parameter.

    Parameters
    ----------
    timeout : float
        Timeout in seconds
    prompt : str
        Prompt to print
    echo : bool
        If True, echo keys to screen as they are pressed
    None_on_timeout : bool
        If this parameter is True and timeout is reached, None is returned.
        Otherwise a (possibly empty) str of characters read so far is returned

    Returns
    -------
    str or None
        Characters read

    Observations
    ------------
    Requires pynput. All caveats of pynput apply to this function. As it
    records keypresses some differences with plain input behavior are expected.
    """
    rv = []
    print(prompt, end='')
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        while timeout > 0:
            start_time = monotonic()
            event = events.get(timeout)
            if event is not None:
                if isinstance(event, keyboard.Events.Press):
                    try:
                        if isinstance(event.key.char, str):
                            if echo:
                                print(event.key.char, end='')
                            rv.append(event.key.char)
                    except AttributeError:
                        if event.key == keyboard.Key.enter:
                            return ''.join(rv)
            timeout -= monotonic() - start_time
    return None if None_on_timeout else ''.join(rv)


def timeout_getchar(timeout:float, prompt:str=''):
    """Read a single char with timeout.
    
    On timeout the return value is None

    Parameters
    ----------
    timeout : float
        Timeout in seconds
    prompt : str
        Prompt to print

    Returns
    -------
    str or None
        Character read

    Observations
    ------------
    Requires pynput. All caveats of pynput apply to this function. As it
    records keypresses some differences with plain input behavior are expected
    """
    print(prompt, end='')
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        while timeout > 0:
            start_time = monotonic()
            event = events.get(timeout)
            if event is not None:
                if isinstance(event, keyboard.Events.Press):
                    try:
                        if isinstance(event.key.char, str):
                            return event.key.char
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
            timeout -= monotonic() - start_time
    return None

promotedPiece = timeout_getchar(5, "Promote to Q, R, B or N? >  ")
print()
if promotedPiece is None:
    print("You took too long. I choose Q for you")
    promotedPiece = 'Q'
promotedPiece = promotedPiece.upper()
if promotedPiece not in ["Q", "R", "B", "N"]:  # If not valid input, choose Queen
    print(f"I said Q, R, B or N. You can not choose {promotedPiece}. I choose Q for you")
    promotedPiece = 'Q'
print("selection = ", promotedPiece)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a few hours, and this is as far as I got:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

global timer
timer = 5

def get_answer():
    answer = input ("ANSWER THE QUESTION!!!")

def runtime():
    global timer
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        timer = timer-1
        print (timer)
        if timer == 0:
            thread1.terminate()
            thread1.join()
            print ("hi")
            break

# create two new threads
thread1 = Process(target=get_answer, args=())
thread2 = Process(target=runtime, args=())

# start the threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# wait for the threads to complete
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

All you need to do is work out the error I'm getting with the `Process` module, and you'll be good.